# Help to identify this weed? Growing in outside veggie pot, used to be strawberry plant. Smells like mint

Tags: identification, herbs

[image]

Just need help to identify this. Is it a weed or?

It is growing in a pot that I had a strawberry plant in last summer and it has a minty smell to it.

Comment: It's a plant, not a weed.